# Downloading files from Google Cloud Storage straight into HDFS and Hive tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on Windows command line as problems with Unix and firewalls prevent `gsutil` from working. I can read my Google Cloud Storage files and copy them over to other buckets (which I don't need to do). What I'm wondering is how to download them directly into HDFS (which I'm 'ssh'ing into)? Has anyone done this? Ideally this is part one, part two is creating Hive tables for the Google Cloud Storage data so we can use HiveQL and Pig.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I can download them straight into my C:Users/Me ...and then upload to HDFS, but rather cut this process to be tighter by going straight to hdfs.  Thanx

Comment: On a Linux box you could pipe the GS download into the HDFS upload on a single command line. On Windows, though...

Comment: BTW, what do you mean exactly about "ssh-ing into HDFS"?!? Are you using a command line such as `hdfs dfs -put`, the WebHDFS REST interface, or some Microsoft contraption?

Comment: yep using Unix to access Hadoop, then using hdfs dfs -commands.  Completely unable to connect through gsutil on Unix though, so the middle integration bit has me stumped. do you know an angry engineer who might have a solution?

Comment: From Windows you should be able to connect to WebHDFS -- either with `curl` or with a custom PowerShell script (see for instance http://poshcode.org/4825) and upload your file. If your SysAdmin favors HttpFS over WebHDFS, it's no big deal. If your SysAdmin set up Kerberos security... now that's a challenge, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878290/accessing-kerberos-protected-webhdfs-from-net-applicationconsole/33892887#33892887

Comment: Ah, I forgot a caveat: when you upload a file with `hdfs dfs` or `hadoop distcp` a temp file name is used until upload is complete. Not so with WebHDFS: the file is created under its real name, and if it is larger than 1 block (e.g. 128 MB) then it will be visible to other HDFS clients as soon as the DataNode notifies the NameNode that block #1 is flushed. So it might be detected, and read, while incomplete (especially if your upload link has low bandwidth).

Comment: All sounded like a perfect solution- until you got to Kerberos! Which we have...every turn there is another wall!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/google-cloud-storage-connector) which provides an HDFS-API compatible interface to your data already in Google Cloud Storage, so you don't even need to copy it anywhere, just read from and write directly to your Google Cloud Storage buckets/objects.

Once you set up the connector, you can also copy data between HDFS and Google Cloud Storage with the `hdfs` tool, if necessary.

Comment: Hey Misha, am I reading this right, the HDFS is in Google Cloud, and the ability to copy data between HDFS and Google seems one-way, HDFS TO google cloud, not from.  This is extremely limiting for larger companies who have huge datasets in their local HDFS and want to join data together for analysis, which is what I'm working on.  To have to move everything into Google Cloud isn't a viable option.  Unfortunately one way data transfers like this make the use of the data difficult, which kinda therefore makes it worthless. :-(

Comment: @sadiemac — it's not one-way, it's bi-directional. Did you try it and it didn't work for you, or are you assuming that it's one-way only? Or did the documentation imply this somehow? In which case, please let me know what led you to this conclusion so that we can fix it, as that's not at all the case.

Comment: Sorry, Misha, I understand you can also move data to HDFS IN google cloud, in that respect I guess it's bi-directional, but replicating data from local HDFS to Google Cloud HDFS isn't what I'm after either.  Integrating data from Google Cloud with local HDFS Cluster is what I'm after.  Yes the Connector documentation implies all these transitions can only occur within Google Cloud and Cloud HDFS.e.g  'The Google Cloud Storage connector for Hadoop lets you run Hadoop or Spark jobs directly on data in Cloud Storage,'

Comment: @sadiemac — you can also run the GCS connector locally, run HDFS locally, and use `hdfs` to move data between them. You will end up copying data into and out of GCS as a result, but via the HDFS API. Is that what you're looking for? Thanks for the feedback on the docs, I'll share it with the team.